# Save Multiple CKRecords At One Time Using CloudKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

Is it possible to save multiple `CKRecord` objects in one `CloudKit` operation using Swift? I know how to retrieve multiple records at once, using things like `CKFetchRecordsOperation` or even just a regular `performQuery`.  I just realized that I am not sure of a way to save multiple new records in one operation.  The way I have been doing that so far, seems inefficient to me.  For example:

```
let recordsToSave:[CKRecord]!

for newRecord in recordsToSave {

    if let database = self.publicDatabase {

        database.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) in

            // Check if there was an error
            if error != nil {

                // There was an error, handle it properly.

            }
            else {

                // There wasn't an error
                if let savedRecord = record {

                    // Handle saved record accordingly.

                }

            }
        })
}
```

And while that does work all fine and dandy, it seems to me as though it's extremely inefficient.  I would think it would make more sense to have a specific function to call to save the entire array of `CKRecords`, instead of having to make a database call every time through the loop.  Essentially here is what I'm **hoping** I can do:

```
let recordsToSave:[CKRecord]!

if let database = self.publicDatabase {

    // SOMETHING HERE LIKE database.saveRECORDS (plural) ????
    database.saveRecords(recordsToSave, completionHandler: { (records:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) in

        // Check if there was an error
        if error != nil {

            // There was an error, handle it properly.

        }
        else {

                // There wasn't an error
                if let savedRecords = records {


                }

            }
        })
}
```

As best as I can tell, and based on the information I've obtained.  There isn't an actual function like `database.saveRecords` (plural).  Unless I am missing something? I'm thinking that its not so cut and dry and that the naming is different, but I would assume there has to be something similar to that.

It seems so horribly inefficient to have to make a database call every time I go through the loop.

Does anybody know of a method to execute a save for multiple `CKRecords` at one time, using `CloudKit`?  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `saveRecord` in a loop is terribly inefficient. It's actually best to avoid all of the convenience methods on `CKDatabase` and use the appropriate operation.

To add/modify/delete one or more records, use `CKModifyRecordsOperation`. You can add/modify as well as deleted any number of records with a single operation. This will be vastly more efficient than using `saveRecord`.

I suggest you browse through the [CloudKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014064) to see the complete list of operations available.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  I had forgotten I could use `CKModifyRecordsOperation` for saving multiple records, I've used it so much before to delete things but never for saving.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To build on what rmaddy said, here is an example code, which also works for deleting if you add an array of CKRecords in the "delete" parameter (which I have as nil here). Here's what I mean:

```
let db = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation.init(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { _, _, error in
    if let error = error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Operation Failed", message: "There was a problem interacting with some records.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok  = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
db.add(operation)
```